# source-map for unmatched line numbers in js with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps, webpack-2

I have an output script from webpack with the sourcemap file. I have another microservice running on some other server which appends/prepends the output script which messes up the line numbers and as a result sourcemap stops working.

What could be possible workarounds for that ? How about manually editing the sourcemap file to ignore the lines added later ? or do I have a better option to have the source map working.

**Edit: I added as many ';' as the lines microservice is adding in the mappings property of the MAP object and the sourcemap started to work again.**